# pdf2htmlEX converts text but not visible (program can't find font file on linux?)

Tags: linux, fonts, fontconfig

I'm using `pdf2htmlEX` to convert a pdf to html, and the output displays correctly when it's generated locally on a mac, but not when it's generated in production on amazon linux. Multiple pages have this issue, but I'll use page 22 of this [pdf](http://artsites.ucsc.edu/sdaniel/170a_2014/head_first_html_css_xhtml.pdf) as a specific example.

For the incorrect html output (generated on linux):

1. while certain text is not visible when it's rendered in the browser, the correct text is in the underlying html upon inspection with chrome dev tools
2. which is caused by the element's css `visibility` attribute (specified by class name `ff13`) being set to `hidden`, where in the correct conversion it is set to `visible`
3. and I can see in dev tools under the css styles computed tab for `rendered fonts` that the correct font is `DejaVu Sans` and the incorrect font is `Helvetica`

I checked and confirmed that `DejaVuSans.ttf` (and other DejaVu fonts) is installed on the linux machine at `/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/`, so my best guess is that for some reason the `pdf2htmlEX` program can't find the font file when it does the conversion, so it marks the css `visibility` property as `hidden`. I also tried to install the core [mac](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-get-mac-and-windows-fonts-in-ubuntu-linux/) (source [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7lHOGlpWanGSDFpbHZJUy1mNFk/edit)) and [microsoft](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-install-microsoft-truetype-fonts-in-centos-6-rhel-6.html) fonts, reboot the machine, and try again, but it didn't seem to help.

I checked `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` and I see under `<!-- Font directory list -->` the directory `<dir>/usr/share/fonts</dir>`. I copied the font files from `/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/` to `/usr/share/fonts/`, and rebooted, but it didn't seem to work. When I run sudo `fc-cache -f -v`, I see `/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/`, and when I run `fc-list` I see various `DejaVu Sans` entries.

Does anyone know either how to fix this or troubleshoot from here? Thanks in advance for any help!